# Header does not redirect an Unset Does not Unset

Tags: php, session, redirect, mysqli

I have this code that works fine, just I cannot seem to have the UNSET command and the header command to work.

I tried to move them around inside my code but without luck. The syntax cannot be wrong (i think) is there any wrongdoing in the location of the commands?

The function works fine, I receive the success message but no redirect. I have seen in a tutorial that somebody uses   include "../html/Search.php"; but when I try to do it, the Search page appears in the middle of the page.

Here is my code:

```
function UpdateCompanies($connection, $tax, $address, $city, $country, $status, $website, $company_foundation ) {
 $n = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $name);
 $t = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $tax);
 $a = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $address);
 $c = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $city);
 $ct= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $country);
 $s= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $status);
 $w= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $website);
 $f= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $company_foundation);
 $e= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $company_employees);

 $query = "UPDATE `seta`.`companies` SET `tax_number`='$t',`street`='$a', `city`='$c', `country_id`='$ct',`status`='$s',`website`='$w',`foundation_year`='$f', `employees`='$e'  WHERE `company_id`='".$_SESSION["company_mod"]."'  ;";


  if ($connection->query($query) === TRUE) {

    echo "New record Updated successfully.";
    header('Location: Search.php');
    unset($_SESSION['company_mod']);

 } else {
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $connection->error;
}
}
```

Please note that I promise I will sanitise more my variables as soon as I make this part of code working.

Comment: You cannot send headers after `echo`ing anything!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send headers after `echo`ing anything!
Maybe you can use this code

```
header( "Refresh:5; url=http://www.example.com/page2.php", true, 303);
echo "New record Updated successfully.";
unset($_SESSION['company_mod']);
```

Also, I advise you to remove the error message of MySQL. Because that can be a security breach

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to work with this code?:

```
function UpdateCompanies($connection, $tax, $address, $city, $country, $status, $website, $company_foundation ) {
 $n = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $name);
 $t = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $tax);
 $a = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $address);
 $c = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $city);
 $ct= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $country);
 $s= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $status);
 $w= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $website);
 $f= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $company_foundation);
 $e= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $company_employees);

 $query = "UPDATE `seta`.`companies` SET `tax_number`='$t',`street`='$a', `city`='$c', `country_id`='$ct',`status`='$s',`website`='$w',`foundation_year`='$f', `employees`='$e'  WHERE `company_id`='".$_SESSION["company_mod"]."'  ;";


  if ($connection->query($query) === TRUE) {

    echo "New record Updated successfully.";
    unset($_SESSION['company_mod']);
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.replace='http://example.com/';</script>"; 
    exit;

 } else {
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $connection->error;
 }
}
```